# Clear All styles except Headings with macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to write a macro to remove all style except headers from a document.
I have this macro that remove all styles:

```
Sub clearstyle()
    ActiveDocument.Select
    Selection.ClearFormatting
end Sub
```

How can I improve this to keep only headers style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```vb
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  If Left(p.Style, 7) <> "Heading" Then
    p.Range.Select
    Selection.ClearFormatting
  End If
Next
```